# Suitable books for further study on mathematical analysis

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, vector-analysis, book-recommendation

I have self-studied mathematical analysis using books written by people from my country. These books cover traditional topics including green formula and stokes formula ($\mathbb{R}^3$ form). However,I want a more solid basis of multivariate analysis, so I'm looking for a book which that introduces multivariate analysis rigorously and comprehensively.

Also, I sometimes encounter the so-called divergence theorem(i.e. problems in Stein's Fourier analysis), which is the general form of stokes formula, and I would like the book to cover such kind of topics.

Is there any book that fit these requirements(using either Riemann or Lebesgue Integral)?

Comment: have you looked at the classic books like Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, James Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds and also Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus?

Comment: You may also look at the following Dover reprints, all entitled "Advanced Calculus", authored by (1) [Friedman](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486457958), (2) [Widder](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-David-V-Widder/dp/0486661032), (3) [Edwards Jr.](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Several-Variables-Mathematics/dp/0486683362), and (4) [Nickerson, Spencer and Steenrod](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486480909). As Dover reprints, all of them are inexpensive.